# How to create amazing looking low poly stone wall?

Tags: modeling, materials

I am trying to create a dungeon in Blender and I want to add some low poly stone walls to it.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a quick way to create this kind of low-poly stones: The ***Bisect*** tool:

- On the tool panel, keep pressing on the *Knife* tool button to have access to the *Bisect*.
- Select your object, go in *Edit* mode, select the edges you want to cut (probably select all), use the bisect.
- Change the options in the *Operator* box (*Inner* or *Outer* to choose what part you want to cut off, *Fill* to keep the object closed).
- Select all to redo. There might be some shortcuts to redo easily (and not loose the last *Operator* settings) but I don't know them.
- Add some details with the knife if necessary (last picture).
- Link-duplicate (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) the stone to only use several ones in your scene.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using @moonboots method, plus an Array modifier, it is possible to make wall sections.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Blender 2.8 has a built-in tool for making brick walls with a few clicks! Make sure you enable the add-on in the Preferences: Add Mesh:Extra Objects.

After that, go to the Add > Mesh > Extras > Wall Factory in the viewport menu. Add a wall and start tweaking. I hope this helps to start!

[image: Navigate to Wall factory in the viewport menu]
[image: Tweak the parameters in Wall Factory]

Comment: I tested it and it's a combination of good and not so good tools. This one is not so good as eg. bricks are not the same size.